# TLS/SSL in .net

Tags: c#, sockets, ssl

Is there any (hopefully free/open source) code available that does native TLS/SSL communication? I do not speak about the HTTPListener/Client and WebRequest classes. I'd like to do raw TLS communication in my C# code.

Thanks in advance,
Max

Comment: Don't you mean TLS = transport layer security?

Comment: Thanks! Of course I meant TLS

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here's an article on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sslclasses.aspx), it also includes code for using OpenSSL.

Do you mind if I ask what you're trying to achieve? Just curious really; there's lots of high-level wrapper classes for this kind of thing so you don't normally need to work at this level (not that there's anything wrong with that :-)

Comment: I am planning to develop a universal network debugger for SSL/TLS connections. You could call it a mitm-attack tool, I rather call it a protocol analyzer or protocol debugger, as I do not intend to do illegal things using it.

Comment: Aha I see, sounds interesting!

Comment: How would that be different than a tool such as Wireshark? If you want to do anything more active, using SSPI and/or openssl might not be helpful, as you will need to modify the actual TLS messages and libraries won't let you do it (definitely with SSPI).

Answer (score 2):

http://www.mentalis.org/soft/projects/ssocket/ - been using this in a commercial product for the last 5 years in .net 1.0, 2.0 and now 3.0. Very reliable, simple to use and stable.

Answer (score 1):

Built-in (as at time of writing) `SslStream` object makes this easy - see https://www.medo64.com/2014/09/client-authenticated-tls-in-c/