# Transport Layer Security (TLS) Examples?

Tags: .net, security, ssl

I got tasked with changing our services that connect to an outside data warehouse to change our connections to TLS. I have searched the web over and have not found any simple examples on how to implement it. The previous programmers set the services up like the following. I will be the first to admit I have never done secure connections so all this is new to me. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
Imports System
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Net.Sockets

m_objClientSocket = New Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
        Dim ep As New IPEndPoint(Dns.Resolve(m_sRemoteHost).AddressList(0), m_iRemotePort)
        m_objClientSocket.Connect(ep)
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/929720/tls-ssl-in-net) here in which an answer directed people to [this article on CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2642/SSL-TLS-client-server-for-NET-and-SSL-tunnelling).  This project is in turn based on the [OpenSSL library](http://www.openssl.org/).

You can also take a look at the [SslStream class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.aspx) in the [System.Net.Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hse0k89h.aspx) namespace.  For example, [see this excellent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695802/using-ssl-and-sslstream-for-peer-to-peer-authentication) and answer.

Comment: Yes I already looked through that example and I had a hard time understanding it. There must be something simpler out there.

Comment: After even more searching everything is saying I need a 3rd party product for secure FTP? Is this correct?

Comment: It's been a long time since I had to implement SSL myself.  When I did it, I had to use a 3rd party product.  However, I noted the SSL support in the System.Net.Security namespace.  See the question I linked for an answer with a step-by-step tutorial.